# Rails Bundle Options for Getting Gems back into your Local Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran `bundle --without development` on my machine and now I want to include the dependencies in my development group in my local rails app.

I ran `bundle` thinking it would including everything again including development, but I receive this message `Gems in the groups development were not installed` still. Can you tell me the option I need to pass into the bundle command to get the development gems back into my application? I tried running  `bundle --include development` with no luck.

Can you also tell me where you found the option (if thats the solution)? I can't seem to locate a list of bundle options.

Comment: if you run a typical `bundle` it doesn't include development now? have you tried running `bundle update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
bundle help install
```

then both the `with` and `without` options are documented. Note that `without` is listed as being a  "remembered option" i.e. it is persisted for subsequent calls.

Remembered options are stored in `.bundle/config` at the root of the project. You can either edit this file directly or view them using

```
bundle config
```

Which will also take into account user level configuration or environment variables that affect bundler

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to confirm this behavior. It seems like the `without --development` flag is saved, so even if you `rm Gemfile.lock`, running bundle again will not install the development group. `bundle update` also doesn't work.

You were close, though, with `bundle --include development`.

What works is `bundle --with development`. You don't need to delete your Gemfile.lock before doing this.